# HTML Include file

Tags: html, server-side-includes

I have a basic web application packaged as an EAR deployed on GlassFish.
The web module has some html files.
The html files have a common footer, an html file, that I would like to extract out and make an include.
When I do, and put:

```
<!--#include virtual="insertthisfile.html" -->
```

in an html file, it does not work.
Should this work?

Comment: i add this in the html: #include virtual="insertthisfile.html", with html like comment tags, which do not show up on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a technique called Server-Side Includes (SSI).  It may not be enabled on your web host.  If it is, sometimes they force a `.shtml` extension to be required for included files, so try renaming your file `insertthisfile.shtml`.

If that doesn't work, you might be able to enable SSIs in a `.htaccess` file (assuming your web server is Apache).  You can find instructions on how to do this by googling.  There's a [decent set here](http://www.ssi-developer.net/ssi/enabling-ssi.shtml).

If that fails, I would contact your web host and see if they have SSIs enabled.

Answer (score 0):

> Should this work?
>   Perhaps, at some special settings, with some experienced programmer, this could be useful.
>   In my case the include statement seems to be ignored.

I could include some text with

```
(embed src="include.shtml")
(/embed)
```

Above, I type `()` instead of angular brackets.

With the "embed", the setting in the header of the page does not apply to the included text; it should be repeated again, and, by default, the result is ugly.
It looks strange, as if the designers of the html did not build-in the very basic tool, the include command. For short articles, the include could save an order of magnitude in the size of files.